# missing ) after argument list in EJS render

Tags: javascript, node.js, rendering, ejs, missing-data

There's this file on my partials folder, "**productosofertas.ejs**", which is included in my views file "**ofertas.ejs**".

This is **ofertas.ejs** code:

```
<%- include("partials/head") -%>
<%- include("partials/header") -%>

<section class="d-block"  style="margin-top: 180px;">
    <div>
        <img src="./images/publcidad-celenste.JPG" style="width: 100%;" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <img src="./images/publicidad-rosa.JPG" style="width: 50%;" alt="">
        <img src="./images/publicidad-azul.JPG" style="width: 50%;" alt="">
    </div>
</section>
<%- include("partials/productosofertas") -%>

<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

However, there is an error on my page every time I type in the route of this ejs file:

SyntaxError: C:\Users\VP\Desktop\ecom\ECOMMERCE\views\ofertas.ejs:12
10|

```
11| </section>

12| <%- include("partials/productosofertas") -%>

13| 

14| <%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

missing ) after argument list in (my PC route)\ECOMMERCE\views\partials\productosofertas.ejs while compiling ejs

I tried reading the code to find the missing character again and again but everything seems to be OK. I also looked up for help in other questions related to this here but I still haven't found a solution.

This is **productosofertas.ejs** code:

```
<div class="others" style="margin-top: 2em;">
    <div class="row">
        <%     ofertasrender.docs.forEach((elemento){     %>
        <div class=" col-md-3 my-4">
                    <div class="position-relative" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
                        <img src="<%= elemento.imagen  %>" alt="">
                        <% const texto = elemento.precio;  %>
                        <% const regex = /(\d+)\s*(?=%)/g;  %>
                        <% const descuento = texto.match(regex); %>

                        <%  if (descuento) {  %>
                        <p class="discount2-pageofertas"><%= descuento[0]  %>% desc.</p>
                        <% } %>
                    </div>
                    <p class="other-title"><%= elemento.nombre  %></p>
                    <p><%= elemento.precio.replace(elemento.nombre,'')  %></p>
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <div class="product-counter other-product-counter">
                        <button class="counter-button other-counter-button">-</button>
                        <p>2</p>
                        <button class="counter-button other-counter-button">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <p><b>Añadir cantidad</b></p>
                </div>
                <button class="add-to-cart-btn other-add-to-cart-btn">Añadir al carrito</button>
            <a href="/product?id=<%= elemento.id %>&coleccion=<%= elemento.coleccion %>"> ver producto</a>
        </div>  
        <% }) %>  
    </div>
</div>
<nav aria-label="...">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center">
      <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
        <a class="page-link" href="/ofertas?page=1&&a=1">1</a>
      </li>
      <% for ( var i = ofertasrender.page; i < ofertasrender.totalPages; i++) { %>
        <%  if(i<=a && i != 1){%>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/ofertas?page=<%=i%>&&llave=true&&a=<%=i%>"><%= i %></a></li>
        <% } else if(i>a && i < ofertasrender.totalPages){ %>
            <span>.</span>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#"><%=  ofertasrender.totalPages %></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `.forEach` method, the callback function syntax is incorrect. (The error is typical for a function call, see: [SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list)).

Replace:

```
<%     ofertasrender.docs.forEach((elemento){     %>
```

with this:

```
<%     ofertasrender.docs.forEach((elemento)=>{     %>
```

Comment: It worked, gosh! I knew it was something so stupid I wouldn't even think about... how frustrating. Thanks a lot!